# WPF application UI hanging because of runtime exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am working on a enterprise level WPF application, we have a lot of modules in this application. while processing long running operations if there are any unexpected exceptions occurs UI thread is not responding. Below I have mentioned sample scenario of mine, please check once.

**Button click:**
await LongRunningOperation();

```
public async Task LongRunningOpertaion()
{
try
{
//some processing will be done here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//here ui hanging
}
}
```

So how can we overcome UI hanging , if there are any exceptions occurred in any long running operations. I have tried Task.Run, Backgroundworker but no luck.

please find the sample application download link [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au_uV-cdd05PlDmbTG2QjbNB8enV)

Thanks.

Comment: You did bot provide a code where application actually hangs. What's inside that catch block?

Comment: i already provided a sample application download link in the question could you please check once.

Comment: @dev ssc, I wouldn't download your code to look at the problem... I don't see why you can't post the code in the catch block... Think about if you were a user looking at the site and giving 5 min of your time while drinking your coffee to help someone else, would you sit there downloading code or go to the next question?

Comment: @JohnChris, i didnt post code in the question itself, instead attached the complete solution, the reason why i attached was we wont be able to see the ui hang untill we run the sample which i have attached. once after downloading the sample if you put no of loops to more than 100 we can observe ui hanging.

Comment: Have downloaded and run and it works as one would expect. UI is updated and I can move the shell window around whilst the UI is updated and the progress ring works as expected.

Comment: @JackHughes, thanks for checking, may i know the no of loops you have tried with ?

Comment: Did the default (50) then tried 10,000. Both worked fine.

Comment: when i test no of loops with 5000, after 200 items progress ring seems little bit jerky. so my requirement is how can we eliminate that jerky behaviour.

Comment: Update the UI less often. Instead of updating the UI after every single item, update every 5 or 10 times. There was no jerkyness when I tested it. My PC is i7 with 16gigs of RAM so can probably cope with lots of updates.

Comment: ok. if you don't mind  I have a small doubt do catch blocks run in main ui thread ?

Comment: could you please increase no of loops a bit more like 20000.

Comment: Increased number of loops to 20000 and there was one short period of UI delay. You can find out which thread the catch is running by breakpointing it and looking at the current thread. When you start the app, breakpoint somewhere at startup and record the GUI thread id. If the catch is running on a different thread then it isn't running on the GUI thread.